# find a record that match another one (from another table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three tables `user`, `event`, `expected_event`

- My `event` are scrapped (every day with a rake task) from another
  website
- A `user` can create `expected_event`

**So What I want to do is:**
When a new `event` is found I want it to be compared to the Users `expected_event`...
If an `event` matches to any users `expected_event` then the users receive an email with the matching `event` `(event.department, event.location_name)`

I want to compare **`event.department`** to **`expected_event.department`**

I don't know how to do this...

**expected_event.rb**

```
class ExpectedEvent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :department, presence: true
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :expected_events
end
```

In the **event model** I have some methode to retreive `city_name`,  `location_name`and `department`

```
  class Event < ApplicationRecord
     def department
       self.city[/\(.*?\)/].gsub(/[()]/, "").to_i
     end

     def city_name
       self.city[/^[^\(]+/].rstrip!
     end

     def location_name
       self.city[/\|(.*)/].gsub("|", "").strip
     end
  end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171210203403) do

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "date"
    t.string   "city"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "nickname"
    ####
  end

  create_table "expected_events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "department"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_expected_events_on_user_id"
  end

end
```

### EDIT

Is it correct if I add something like this to my user model?

```
  has_many :matching_events, through: :events, source: :expected_events
```

Comment: You should first create proper rails [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) between all 3 models. And then, using [JOINS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) ,you should fetch your data and compare.

Answer (score 0):

When a new event is created, why don't you just query for `ExpectedEvent` records with matching paramters. Something like

```
event = Event.create(event_params)

if ExpectedEvent.where(city: event.city, ...).any?
  #send email to user about the event
end
```

Comment: When I scrap the website the `city` is a long string that looks like this:  
"CLERMONT FERRAND (63) |  Le Zenith" 
I need to display it a bit differently in my index page, that's why I did the little methods  in the `event` Model.
My ExpectedEvent are created by department number ....
So if my department number is *36* I should receive an email  that there is a show in Clermont Ferrant... blablabla....